# Is it ok to modify part of prevState inside setState?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a real disadvantage to modifying part of prevState and returning that part inside setState() ?

Example:

```javascript
this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState.myObject.isItTrue = !prevState.myObject.isItTrue;
    return {myObject: prevState.myObject};
});
```

Rather than:

```javascript
this.setState(prevState => {
    const myObject = Object.assign({}, prevState.myObject);
    myObject.isItTrue = !myObject.isItTrue;
    return {myObject: myObject};
});
```

Is there any real disadvantage to the first code where I save myself the `Object.assign()` ?

EDIT: If I am correct, prevState.myObject is simply a reference to this.state.myObject, so changing prevState.myObject actually changes this.myObject.object as well! However, this doesn't seem to break anything, as long as I use setState() to pass an object that contains the new data, even if it's just a reference to the old objects inside this.state. 
Do you agree that this is still ok, i.e. it won't break anything to do it like this?

Comment: I have a different question, why do you need all this logic inside the setState? way not do it outside

Comment: There is not anything wrong, per se, with what you are doing since you are returning a new object, but any pure function that mutates inputs or otherwise has side effects is not pure functional programming. You should not mutate the old state.

Comment: @Roy.B, can you give an example of how to "do it outside" ?

Comment: @DrewReese there is actually something wrong. The state object is a new one, but the `myObject` is the same object and so when passed around, other components will not know that is has been altered. So as a principle you should always create new objects and arrays inside state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `prevState` and the `this.state` are the same object. So you are modifying the actual state directly.

Secondly, down the road you might pass the `myObject` as a prop to another component, and since it will be the same object always that component will not know that something has changed and it will not re-render (*for example `PureComponent` and ones that implement `componentDidUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` and test for changes*)

See https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-aryabhata-m07l4 for showcases of all issues.

So you should use

```js
this.setState(state => ({
      myObject: {
        ...state.myObject,
        isItTrue: !state.myObject.isItTrue
      }
    }));
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! There's a parenthesis missing at the end of your code snippet. I modified the codesandbox link to reflect your proposed solution and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sea-o7khy

Answer (score 7):

Following documentation:

> **state** is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

So you should not apply changes directly to that state.

Either way, why not do something like this?:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    myObject : {
        ...prevState.myObject,
        isItTrue: !prevState.myObject.isItTrue,
    }
}));
```

This way will get all the elements from the **prevState** but also change all the ones you want to modify.

Comment: As I mentioned in my EDIT above, I believe it is actually a reference to this.state, not a copy. If I modify prevState.myObject, I am in fact modifying this.state.myObject. I tested this by returning `{anotherObject: myObject}` and found that this.state.myObject was modified as well.

Comment: The `spread`ing you do is wrong as you are spreading the internals of `myObject` inside the state and not inside a `myObject` property

Comment: Indeed you were both right, I've made the changes to my response. Thanks :)